# How to Open app Outlook on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there a way that pressing on a button opens Outlook, with my email address already inserted as a recipient?

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //??
        }
```

I need programically fill:  to and subject information

Comment: Providing a more specific title than 'How to open Outlook' would be useful.

Comment: I would like to open the Outlook app on Windows Phone  to send email

Comment: What if the user has more than one Account setup on the phone?

Comment: [EmailComposeTask.To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask.to%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: It is often found on the link "mailto: aaa@bbb.com". Clicking automatically opens the mail program

Answer (score 2):

You can use the share Email Task with all your field Areas predefined. It will not only allow you to open outlook but all the email accounts on the phone.

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";

emailComposeTask.Show();
```

It requires Microsoft.Phone.Task library

Comment: because I do not find that namespace?

Comment: its available only as your tag says windowsphone-8 and below silverlight os. for universal Apps there are Async Uri schemes